# Is this asbestos? How to handle this?

Tags: drywall, walls, door-frame, asbestos

My grandmoom had a family member replace doors in her home and when he took parts of wall down (and left it like this) a bunch of dust and debris got all over the rugs and furniture. Her house is old and she doesn't care, but I'm concerned if this asbestos or not. I've been told it's Horsehair plaster. [image]

Google says Horsehair plaster MAY contain Asbestos. My grandmother says her home was made around the 1930's. I haven't the eye, is there any asbestos? And I've read even after dusting it isn't safe to put exposed/covered sheets and clothing that have in a washing machine cause it get other tings in future washes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody can tell if it's asbestos from a picture. It needs a lab test.

Comment: I've read a comment somewhere on this site that horsehair plaster also poses a health risk ... I do not remember exactly what the risk actually is, but I think that it is something biological, perhaps ecoli

Answer (score 3):

It might be asbestos. Impossible to tell without sending samples to a lab for testing. But keep in mind that asbestos is not cyanide of plutonium. For *most* people, a little bit is no big deal. The primary issue is *repeated* exposure to airborne fibers. So a general recommendation, which applies to many forms of fibers, dust, etc. from construction is:

- While wearing a properly fitting face mask (hasn't been too hard to find those for the last few years), vacuum up all the dust from walls, floor, furniture, etc. Use a vacuum cleaner with a bag, and dispose of the bag when done.
- Wash any exposed clothing.
- Cover up any exposed problem surfaces.

This last one is key to asbestos, and is also important for lead paint (especially if there are small children around). Asbestos hidden inside a wall is not dangerous. Asbestos crumbling/falling out of an open wall is potentially dangerous. So if you don't know what it is, sealing it up avoids the problem. A layer of drywall is often the easiest way to do that.

Comment: May I suggest this answer add that the vacuum use a HEPA filter. It's an extra expense, but otherwise you risk making the problem worse.